How to get the publicly downloadable url from wix collections/database?
I am trying to get the publicly downloadable link from Wix Collections but somehow I manage to always get a link that is referenced internally in wix or a link that just displays the pdf in a new tab with the option of manually downloading it.
How do I get the publicly downloadable link which I can call into my EC2 Machine to use it further. All I get is a link that opens the pdf url but I would have to download or manually save it instead of downloading it automatically into my EC2 machine as I call the link.
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const itemId = "XXXX";

export function getDocumentDownloadUrl() {
    return wixData.get('fileupload', itemId)
        .then((item) => {
            
            const FileUrl = item.fileUrl; 

            console.log('Downloadable URL:', FileUrl);
            return FileUrl;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('Error retrieving file URL:', err);
            return null;
        });
}

getDocumentDownloadUrl().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
        console.log("Retrieved URL:", url);
    } else {
        console.log("Failed to retrieve URL.");
    }
});

Here's the code I am trying to do.

You can generate a download link from the internal Wix link. Use the generateFileDownloadUrl() function.
